Why am I unable to bold or italicize a google font in ggplot?
I am having difficulty stylizing google fonts that were downloaded and saved to my Mac's font book. Including a simple example below with a blank plot area.
ggplot() +
  labs(title = "Title in Bold",
       subtitle = "Subtitle in Italics") +
  xlab("Y Label") +
  ylab("X Label") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Raleway"),
        plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 18),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = 'italic')
        )

This yields the below where the correct font is rendered but the bold and italics are not applied to the title and subtitle, respectively. I only get the font in its regular/plain form:

I then try font_import() from extrafont which does return (amongst a lengthier message):
"/Users/username/Library/Fonts/Raleway-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf : Raleway-ThinItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
/Users/username/Library/Fonts/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.ttf : Raleway-Thin already registered in fonts database. Skipping."
If I change the backend graphics to something like AGG then I get warnings of "In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :  Unable to load font: Raleway". Likewise, if I use showtext::showtext_auto() I get the same response.
I am able to utilize Raleway italics/bold in other applications such as Microsoft Word. How can I get these font styles to properly load/register in R?
Session info below in case that's relevant:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0
locale:
1 en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal
attached base packages:
1 stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
1 extrafont_0.19  lubridate_1.9.3 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.1   dplyr_1.1.4     purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.5
[8] tidyr_1.3.1     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.5.0   tidyverse_2.0.0 RPostgres_1.4.6
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
1 cfbfastR_1.9.0     DBI_1.2.2          remotes_2.5.0      writexl_1.5.0      rlang_1.1.3        magrittr_2.0.3
[7] snakecase_0.11.1   furrr_0.3.1        compiler_4.3.3     mgcv_1.9-1         png_0.1-8          systemfonts_1.0.6
[13] vctrs_0.6.5        reshape2_1.4.4     sysfonts_0.8.9     rvest_1.0.4        profvis_0.3.8      crayon_1.5.2
[19] pkgconfig_2.0.3    fastmap_1.1.1      backports_1.4.1    ellipsis_0.3.2     labeling_0.4.3     utf8_1.2.4
[25] promises_1.2.1     rmarkdown_2.26     sessioninfo_1.2.2  tzdb_0.4.0         ps_1.7.6           bit_4.0.5
[31] xfun_0.43          showtext_0.9-7     cachem_1.0.8       jsonlite_1.8.8     blob_1.2.4         later_1.3.2
[37] emoji_15.0         jpeg_0.1-10        broom_1.0.5        parallel_4.3.3     R6_2.5.1           stringi_1.8.3
[43] espnscrapeR_0.8.0  extrafontdb_1.0    parallelly_1.37.1  pkgload_1.3.4      assertthat_0.2.1   Rcpp_1.0.12
[49] knitr_1.45         usethis_2.2.3      pacman_0.5.1       nnet_7.3-19        Matrix_1.6-5       httpuv_1.6.15
[55] splines_4.3.3      timechange_0.3.0   tidyselect_1.2.1   rstudioapi_0.16.0  yaml_2.3.8         codetools_0.2-19
[61] miniUI_0.1.1.1     websocket_1.4.1    curl_5.2.1         processx_3.8.4     listenv_0.9.1      pkgbuild_1.4.4
[67] lattice_0.22-6     plyr_1.8.9         withr_3.0.0        shiny_1.8.1        evaluate_0.23      future_1.33.1
[73] RcppParallel_5.1.7 urlchecker_1.0.1   xml2_1.3.6         pillar_1.9.0       generics_0.1.3     chromote_0.2.0
[79] hms_1.1.3          munsell_0.5.0      scales_1.3.0       globals_0.16.3     xtable_1.8-4       emo_0.0.0.9000
[85] glue_1.7.0         janitor_2.2.0      mlbplotR_1.1.0     tools_4.3.3        data.table_1.15.2  fs_1.6.3
[91] grid_4.3.3         Rttf2pt1_1.3.12    devtools_2.4.5     colorspace_2.1-0   nlme_3.1-164       patchwork_1.2.0
[97] showtextdb_3.0     proto_1.0.0        baseballr_1.6.0    cli_3.6.2          fansi_1.0.6        gt_0.10.1
[103] V8_4.4.2           emojifont_0.5.5    gtable_0.3.4       digest_0.6.35      farver_2.1.1       htmlwidgets_1.6.4
[109] memoise_2.0.1      htmltools_0.5.8    lifecycle_1.0.4    httr_1.4.7         mime_0.12          bit64_4.0.5

I cant open the img since my work blocks it, but when i tried your code it seemed to work.
Might consider this code and see if it works? making use of the tidyverse for mtcars.
enter image description here
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp))+geom_point()+
  labs(title = "Is it italicized?",
       subtitle = "Is it italicized?",
       caption = "Is it italicized?",
       x = "Miles per gallon",
       y = "Displacement")+
  theme(text =element_text(family = "raleway",
                           face = "italic"))

I installed locally the font. Another option is to try and use the ggtext package:
require(ggtext)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp))+geom_point()+
  labs(title = "Is it italicized?",
       subtitle = "*Is it italicized? It is thanks to ggtext::*",
       caption = "Is it italicized?",
       x = "Miles per gallon",
       y = "Displacement")+
  theme(text =element_text(family = "raleway"),
        plot.subtitle = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )

which generated this:
enter image description here
*I use also thematic::thematic_on() and set_theme for convivence, that's why the appearance is a bit different
RVersion:  4.3.2
ggplot2 version": 3.5.0

Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately neither solution worked for me.  Font still displays as regular/plain with no stylization.

It turns out I was not properly loading the font (second line of code below) before attempting showtext::showtext_auto(). Previously, I had included only one of the two arguments in font_add_google.
library(showtext)
font_add_google(name = "Raleway", family = "Raleway") 
showtext_auto()

